# multi-platform javascript RSA encryption

Tags: javascript, encryption, browser, rsa, node-webkit

I'm currently building a multi-platform web application that will be available over the internet as a regular website, on desktop using node-webkit (node js) and also mobile using cordova. Everything uses html/js, so I'll be able to use the same code everywhere (mostly), which is what I'm aiming for!
The application will need to encrypt some sensible data, and I would like to use RSA encryption for it!

The problem I'm facing is that so far I haven't been able to find a pure javascript lib able to do it! And why is that, you ask?! Everything I've tryed so far doesn't work on node-webkit, because of some Uint8Array, Uint16Array or Uint32Array object. Apparently, V8 has some problem with those! Tom Wu's jsbn lib uses that, and since almost every other javascript lib is bases on Tom Wu's, they all have the same problem (ex. jsencrypt, etc.) or are node modules that we cannot use on a browser!

Of course I can always workaround it, detecting if I'm running on node-webkit or not and use a node module if so, and a normal lib otherwhise. But I would really like to keep it homogeneous!

What I need is:
A pure javascrypt (not modular) lib that can RSA encrypt with a public key, that also works on node-webkit's V8. The decription will be made only on the backend (with c++), on the frontend I'll only need javascript to encrypt.

Does anyone know something I could use?